# <td> height not even next to a rowspan in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having an issue in safari. I have a table with two columns and 4 rows. The second column has a rowspan of 4 because it contains an image. the first column is just numbers. In all the other browsers the table lines up fine with the rows all spacing evenly. In safari the rows fit to the content and then the last row is stretched to fill the rest of the space. I have tried setting the table-layout property to fixed but that does not seem to change anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the table:

```
<table>
        <tr>                
            <td>1 - </td>
            <td rowspan=\"4\">
                <img src=\"img/image.jpg\" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 - </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 - </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4 - </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safari bug is caused by the height of an image in the rowspan being taller than the containing table. If you can control/predict what the height of the image will be, you can give an equal height to each table row based on the amount of table rows divided into the height of the image.

In other words:

If you have 4 table rows and your image in the rowspan is 400px tall, you would set the height of each  to 100px.

```
tr {
    height: 100px;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Works just fine. Wonder why only safari has this behavior though. It's fortunate I had to set the height of this image but don't know what I'd do if it were responsive other than divs which might take some doing since the numbers line up to the image.

Comment: @Hirthas For a responsive solution, could your project use an unordered list for the numbers and then float the img to the right?